# Install Postgis in Ubuntu 16.04 in with already postgresql 9.3 installed

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ubuntu

In ubuntu 16.04 with postgresql 9.3 when I tried to install postgis with using command

```
sudo apt-get install postgis postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
```

It installed **postgresql 9.6 and postgis-9.6** version. And when tried to create extension it gives error

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory.
```

Also two servers are running

```
postgres@db:~$ psql
psql (9.6.3, server 9.3.17)
Type "help" for help.
```

Comment: Why do you need to install such an old version (9.3) ? Ubuntu 16.04 defaults to Postgres 9.5. Version 9.6 and 9.3 are both not available . I assume you used some repositories. I guess you used an outdated howto. Such information should be included in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You explicitely installed Version 9.3 and implicitely installed 9.6 as the`postgis` package depends on it. But I don't know why you're missing the postgis extension files for 9.3 then.

You can list dependencies of a package:

```
sudo apt-cache depends postgis
```

Installing just `postgis` should be enough.

---

**Fix by uninstalling older Version:**

Remove version 9.3:

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 postgresql-9.3
```

---

**Keeping multiple PostgreSQL installations; How to use a specific version:**

When multiple versions are installed, a new PostgreSQL cluster is used for each. You need to specify a cluster when using `psql`:

```
psql --cluster 9.6/main -d "YOUR_DATABASE" -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

List available clusters:

```
pg_lsclusters
```